# creation of Step and that can change components React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a component where when I press the following button it changes the component and the Step is updated, but I don't know how to make that when I press the button it changes the component and returns

STEP:

```
import React from "react"
import { Steps } from "rsuite"
import "rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css" // or 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css'
import "./index.css"

export default function Registration() {
  const styles = {
    width: "200px",
    display: "inline-table",
    verticalAlign: "top",
  }
  

  return (
    <div>
      <Steps current={1} vertical style={styles}>
        <Steps.Item title="1" />
        <Steps.Item title="2" />
        <Steps.Item title="3" />
        <Steps.Item title="4" />
      </Steps>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and this would be the component where you sent them to call

```
     import React from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import Com1 from "./Component1";
    import Com2 from "./Component2";
    import Com3 from "./component3";
    import Step from "./Step "
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="w-full flex">
          <Step/>
          <Com1/>
          <Com2/>
          <Com3/>
          <div className="App">
             <button>next</button>
             <button>return</button>
           </div>
        </div>
      );

}
```

each component has a next and back button

Comment: Where do you use `Registration` component and where is the button?

Comment: The buttons are in each component, but I will pass them outside, right now I update the code